# How to prevent Google from indexing redirect URL I do not own

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-307

A domainname that I do not own, is redirecting to my domain. I don´t know who owns it and why it is redirecting to my domain.

This domain however is showing up in Googles search results. When doing a whois it also returns this message:

"Domain:http://[baddomain].com webserver returns 307 Temporary Redirect"

Since I do not own this domain I cannot set a 301 redirect, or disable it. When clicking the baddomain in Google it shows the content of my website but the baddomain.com stays visible in the URL bar.

My question is: How can I stop Google from indexing and showing this bad domain in the search results and only show my website instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

You cannot directly stop Google from indexing other sites, but what you could do is add the cannonical tag to your pages so Google can see that the original content is located on your domain and not "bad domain". 
For example check out : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en

Other actions can be taken SEO wise if the 'baddomain' is outscoring you in the search rankings, because then it sounds like your site could use some optimizing. 
The better your site and domain rank in the SERPs, the less likely it is that people will see the scraped content and 'baddomain'.

You could however also look at the referrer for the request and if it is 'bad domain' you should be able to do a redirect to your own domain, change content etc, because the code is being run from your own server. 
But that might be more trouble than it's worth as you'd need to investigate how the 'baddomain' is doing things and code accordingly. (properly iframe or similar from what you describe, but that can still be circumvented using scripts).

Depending on what country you and 'baddomain' are located in, there are also legal actions. So called DMCA complaints. This however can also be quite a task, and well - it's often not worth it because a new domain will just pop up.

Comment: I have added the canonical tags though Yoast SEO plugin since I use a WP site.

I also have redirected the incoming link from ´baddomain.com´ to my iwn domain via a .htaccess 301 redirect which seems to work.

As for the SEO, my website is still under developement so that´s why the ´baddomain.com´ is ranking higher now. This will probably solve itself then when the site goes live.

Thanks again.